# Parcel localhost server not updating

Tags: javascript, npm, parceljs, parcel

I am using the parcel (v2.0.1) localhost server with hot module replacement to develop a simple HTML/SASS/JS-based web app. The HMR is working fine most of the time, but from time to time, especially when making significant changes to the code, ALL server updating stops working -- i.e. not only does HMR not work, but I can't even get the server to reflect the changes by reloading the browser page completely or even stopping and restarting the server. To make sure I wasn't just missing something simple I made changes to the code that would DEFINITELY break certain features and restarted the server, but the page still worked as normal.

I have also tried deleting the .parcel-cache and dist folders and re-running parcel and that has not worked either. Restarting my computer has not worked either. The only mention I've seen of this problem is [this github discussion](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/1591).

Has anyone had a similar problem? Thanks!

Here is the package.json file:

```js
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "source": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel index.html",
    "build": "parcel build index.html"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.0.1",
    "parcel": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.19.3",
    "fractional": "^1.0.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9"
  }
}
```

Comment: I discovered that the problem (in my case, anyway) was that the project files were all in a cloud folder. Once I moved the files to my local drive everything worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the problem (in my case, anyway) was that the project files were all in a cloud folder. Once I moved the files to my local drive everything worked!

Answer (score 4):

Put this in your script tag:

```
 type="module"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In latest Parcel version. ' type="module" ' is needed for including script in the html file. But before version 2, it can be omitted.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, CSS is still not reloaded when it changes. :/

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem with the following code:

```
    "start": "parcel index.html && parcel watch index.html",
```

Comment: According to the Parcel docs, the commands do almost the same thing so what you have there will just start HMR twice.

https://parceljs.org/features/cli/

Answer (score 1):

Met the same issue: parcel stops working. Especially for me, it happens when I leave a project for day-two and when returned it's broken yet. Even full reinstall (including package.json removing) can't fix the problem. After reinstall, previous broken state is still preserved: it runs recent working code version (I don't understand from where it get the correct code, all data was removed) and doesn't react on any changes except syntax error which cause throwing related errors.